# Getting - ParseObjectSubclass in place of full object of class

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I am facing problem while fetching data in Parse server. I have written my query below:

```
 let meetingObject = {
    "__type": "Pointer",
    "className": "Meeting",
    "objectId": meetingObjectId
  };

  let queryAgendalist = new Parse.Query("Agenda");
  queryAgendalist.equalTo('isPlay', true);
  queryAgendalist.equalTo('meeting', meetingObject);
```

I am getting following result:

```
ParseObjectSubclass { className: 'Agenda', _objCount: 29, id: '54EBbZrLSt' }
```

I am expecting result as

```
results: [{
{ organizers: 
   [ { username: 'anand.solanki@volansystech.com',
       firstname: 'Anand ',
       lastname: 'Solanki',
       email: 'anand.solanki@volansystech.com',
       company: 'Volansys',
       team: 'SBI',
       fullnameLowercase: 'anand  solanki',
       userId: 2,
       createdAt: '2017-04-13T13:47:24.141Z',
       updatedAt: '2017-04-13T13:47:24.141Z',
       ACL: [Object],
       sessionToken: 'r:df8c7895c3ed44e52c0e985559ff2e9a',
       objectId: 'CaeAiWlYPw' } ],
  attendees: 
   [ { __type: 'Pointer', className: '_User', objectId: 'CaeAiWlYPw' },
     { __type: 'Pointer', className: '_User', objectId: 'CaeAiWlYPw' } ],
  title: 'M1 - Agenda1',
  description: 'M1 - Agenda1',
  by: { __type: 'Pointer', className: '_User', objectId: 'CaeAiWlYPw' },
  durationPlanned: '15 min',
  meeting: 
   { __type: 'Pointer',
     className: 'Meeting',
     objectId: 'RAIO0RuWwZ' },
  playOrder: 1,
  agendaId: 20,
  isDeleted: false,
  isPlay: true,
  createdAt: '2017-05-29T07:19:29.818Z',
  updatedAt: '2017-05-30T08:29:33.345Z',
  objectId: '54EBbZrLSt' }]
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: its not really clear to me what you're asking?  When you say what you're expecting, are those the fields in your agenda object?  You can see what is in the returned object by logging what is returned as json.  parse objects have a [toJSON()](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_toJSON) function that you could use.  When you log a parse object, it doesn't print all the fields....

Comment: Did you resolve this? Out of the blue I am getting this. I can't figure what the hell went wrong. But one query just returns this crap suddenly instead of the actual object. Any by the way, your question is supper clear.

Comment: @MehdiAbderezai Yes I resolved this. Actually what I print is not proper way to get details that's why issue faced. Later on check that all the details are coming properly.

Comment: Faced this issue, and the only way to resolve it was to use what Arthur suggested. I'm running my parse server in a docker container and I was seeing the full object in verbose mode there, but in the Parse JS SDK in my NodeJS app, I was only getting what the OP was getting.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and read here's article.

Tried with Arthur Cinader's method.
I can get ParseObjectSubclass content with toJSON().
It is working for me :)